# Construct JSON in proper format with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, x-editable

I am trying to reformat a dynamically created JSON output into a format that can be consumed by the x-editable select type source[]. I need help building the array so that the re-formated JSON output looks like this:

```
{value: 2, name: 'Maintenance'},
```

Below is a sample original JSON which I am consuming:

```
{"COLUMNS":["SECTIONCOMMONNAME"],"DATA":[["Aircraft Overview"],["Email Server Settings"],["Maintenance"],["Page Sections"],["WOW"]]}
```

The code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/3nzdj';
var myarray = [];

$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (e) {
        console.log('My created console output:' +'<br>');
        $.each(e.DATA, function (i, jsonDataElem) {

            console.log("{value: " + i + ', ' + "name: " + '"'+this+"'}");
            var item = {
                "value": i,
                    "name": this
            };
            myarray.push(item);
        });
        var newJson = JSON.stringify(myarray);
        console.log('My stringify output:' +'<br>' +newJson);
    }
});

$('.sectionsAvailable').editable({
    name: 'template',
    type: 'select',
    placement: 'right',
    send: 'always',
    value: 1,
    source: [], //newJson (my new var)

    /* should be in this format:
     source: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'text1'
    }, {
        value: 2,
        text: 'text2'
    }]*/

});


};
```

});

After the stringify, the output is close, but wont work. It looks like this:

```
{"value":2,"name":["Maintenance"]}
```

and needs to look like thisL

```
{value:2,name:'Maintenance'},
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/mj6442zm/) showing the output here.

Comment: `"name" : this[0]` ?

Comment: Thanks, it did help, but the name values are still quoted. To be fair, i needed to update the JSfiddle. Please take a look again...

Comment: Well yes, it's quoted because it's a string. You can't unquote them without breaking your json. If you want `{ value : 0 , name : Aircraft Overview }` you're screwed, this is just invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. There might be a better way, but this works:

```
var myURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/3nzdj';
$.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
var output = '';
  $.each(data.DATA, function(key, val) {
    output +='{value: ';
    output += "'"+key+"'";
    output +=',text:';
    output += "'"+val+"'";
    output +='}';
    output +=',';
});
    var outputAdapted = '['+output+']'
$('.sectionsAvailable').editable({
    name: 'template',
    type: 'select',
    placement: 'right',
    send: 'always',
    value: 1,
     // should be in this format:
     source: 
     function() {
      return outputAdapted;
     },
 });
});
```

My [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/zLsrb0qL/) I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are assigning complete array instead of value at index 0 try this

```
 var item = {
              "value": i,
              "name": this[0] // gives elemnt at index 0
            };
  myarray.push(item);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mj6442zm/1/)

Comment: thank you. This helped, but the name values are still quoted. Is there a way to use eval() to remove the quoted name and value attributes. I updated mu FIDDLE to reflect.

Comment: what is the use case o removing quotes, as per the joson specification http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627 it is better to keep quotes if you want to use as JSON